# SSH connection password setting

Tags: ssh

I connect to a host via SSH with a passphrase. When i am in that host I want to install a few packages for which I have to switch to 'root'. While doing so, it asks for 'Password' and obviously my passphrase doesn't work here. This host is setup only for SSH access. How to get the password details?

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch to the root-user with your own password for obvious reasons. Either you are allowed to *sudo su root* (which may ask for YOUR password) or you do *su root* (which asks for root's password)